# Homomorphism Number of Weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory

I recently read the book "Large Networks and Graph Limits" by Laszlo Lovasz. I have a small doubt on the homomorphism number of graph. (All I used below is the notation of this book)

For simple graph $F$ and $G$, Number of edge of preserving map $\phi:V(F)\to V(G)$, between two graph is defined as homomorphic number and it is always an positive integer (if homomorphism exist)(trivially).

Suppose $F$ is simple graph and $G$ is a weighted graph with $\beta_{ij}$ is the weight of $ij$ edge in $G$.

Now we define,
$$hom_{\phi}(F,G) = \prod_{ij\in E(F)}\beta_{\phi(i)\phi(j)}$$
and the homomorphism number is defined as
$$
hom(F,G) = \sum_{\phi:V(F)\to V(G)}hom_{\phi}(F,G)
$$
Here clearly $hom(F,G)$ is not a positive integer here, since weights are not necessarily an integer.
My question is, how it is possible that number of $hom(F,G)$ is not an integer? I mean, is this possible? If possible what is the correct interpretation, Is this notion is same as first case? Or anything else.

Comment: The homomorphism number is always a non-negative integer, but it is not always positive. For example, there are no homomorphisms from $K_2$ to $K_1$.

Comment: The weighted case is simply a generalization of the unweighted case. If all of the weights in $G$ are $1$, then the "weighted homomorphism number" is equal to the "unweighted homomorphism number". And yes, if $G$ has non-integer weights, then the homomorphism number may fail to be an integer.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk correct, that's why I'm asking is there any natural intuition behind that, like the simple one? Otherwise it is hard to imagine that number of homomorphism between two sets is non-integer quantity. Because homomorphism is nothing but the maps only and we counts how much such maps possible. It may sound idiotic, but I hope I clearly explained my thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for all quantities (not just homomorphisms) the weighted version of counting something is to instead take the total weight of something. For example, rather than the number of edges in $G$, we often want to think about $\sum_{ij \in E(G)} \beta_{ij}$ when $G$ is a weighted graph: the total weight of edges in $G$.

In this case, $\operatorname{hom}(F,G)$ is the total weight of of all copies of $F$ found in $G$. What is the "weight of a copy of $F$"? That's defined by $\operatorname{hom}_\phi(F,G)$: $\phi$ points out a particular copy of $F$ in $G$, and its total weight is the product of the weights of its edges.

If the weights are all equal to $1$, then every copy of $F$ found in $G$ also has weight $1$, and so the total weight of all copies of $F$ is equal to the number of copies of $F$ (that is, the number of homomorphisms). This is how we recover the unweighted case.

Another important intuition-building application is when all weights are between $[0,1]$. Here, define $G_\beta$ to be the random (unweighted) subgraph of $G$ obtained by independently deciding to keep each edge $ij$ with probability $\beta_{ij}$. In this case:

- $\operatorname{hom}_\phi(F,G)$ is the probability that $\phi$ is also a homomorphism from $F$ to $G_\beta$ (in other words, the probability that all the edges in the copy of $F$ survive from $G$ to $G_\beta$).
- $\operatorname{hom}(F,G)$ is the expected value of $\operatorname{hom}(F,G_\beta)$: the expected number of homomorphisms from $F$ to $G_\beta$.

Comment: Thank you very much for nice and very clear answer! It is now clear to me.